# Materialize framework problems

Tags: css, materialize

I have this simple div:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hoverable col s12 l4 m4">
    Hoverable div.
  </div>
</div>
```

The hoverable effect doesn't work on mouse leave while works on mouse hover.

While I use l4 and m4 classes the div still takes 12 columns on my laptop screen.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fv9b3f87/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the columns inside a row. Like this:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="hoverable col s12 m4 l4">Hoverable div.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: You have to add the following css:

```
.hoverable{
    transition: box-shadow 0.25s ease 0s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That solves the grid system problem, but the hoverable effect still not working on mouse leave.